# Avoid field updates when merging and printing word docx with {officer} package

Tags: r, officer

I am stacking two docx, both of which have distinct dates in the title property, linked to fields in the respective documents. I would like the date in docx1 to remain unchanged in the new combined docx ("current.docx") as it is when printed in "docx1.docx", but the natural behavior is for docx2 to also update the field in docx1 to its title property once it has been added with `body_add_docx()` and printed.

```r
library(officer)

# Set dates for docx1 and docx2
date1 <- format(Sys.Date(), "%A, %B %d, %Y")
date2 <- format(Sys.Date() +1, "%A, %B %d, %Y")

# Create docx1 with date1
docx1 <- read_docx()
docx1 <- set_doc_properties(docx1, title = date1)
fp1 <- fpar(
  ftext("Hello"), 
  run_linebreak(),
  run_word_field(field = "DOCPROPERTY \"title\""),
  run_pagebreak()
)
docx1 <- body_add_fpar(docx1, value = fp1)
print(docx1, "doc1.docx")

# Create docx2 with date2, and add docx1 as "current.docx" to show how date1 updates to date2
docx2 <- read_docx()
docx2 <- set_doc_properties(docx2, title = date2)
fp2 <- fpar(
  ftext("World"),
  run_linebreak(),
  run_word_field(field = "DOCPROPERTY \"title\"")
)
docx2 <- body_add_fpar(docx2, value = fp2)
docx2 <- body_add_docx(docx2, "doc1.docx", pos = "before")
print(docx2, "current.docx")

# Create example "desired.docx" retaining date1 and date2 after stacking
docx3 <- read_docx()
fp <- fpar(
  ftext("Hello"), 
  run_linebreak(),
  ftext(date1),
  run_pagebreak(),
  ftext("World"),
  run_linebreak(),
  ftext(date2)
)
docx3 <- body_add_fpar(docx3, value=fp) |>
  print("desired.docx")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Once I have printed docx1, I no longer need the title field, so it seems like converting that field specifically (or even all docx1 fields) to text before printing would make sense as a way of preventing the update. I have tried `body_replace_all_text()`, but that doesn't work because there is no text actual text to find in the field. I have also considered that fields can be converted to text in a word document using Ctrl+Shift+F9 to run the "Selection.Range.Field.Unlink" macro, but am not sure how to do this programatically on many documents using R.

Thank you so much for the package and any guidance you can give.

Comment: It seems like the way to go is to convert the fields in docx1 to text with the Field.Unlink macro either in Excel or equivalent in LibreOffice. If there is some expert source on how to do this in R, maybe with RDComClient, or running from the command line via System(), which I haven't found after two weeks of searching, I would greatly appreciate any pointers. This is a surprisingly lightly documented area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`officer::run_word_field(field = "DOCPROPERTY \"title\"")` appears to be outputting objects of type [`Field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field) with a [`Code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.code) property of `DOCPROPERTY "title"`.

In the example file you uploaded [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mt5Bookp6pyb-Mw1kxfiuaEbXMrsG6KI/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=103165908016833094475&rtpof=true&sd=true), the field appears to be of type [`ContentControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol) with a [`Title`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.title) property of "Title" and an [`XMLMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.xmlmapping) property having an [`XPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.xmlmapping.xpath) property of `/ns1:coreProperties[1]/ns0:title[1]` (i.e., an xml mapping back to the document title).

Here is an updated solution (for Windows) based on the google docs file.

### First Define a Custom Function

This function:

1. Writes your rdox object to a temp docx file
2. Writes a temp VBScript (.vbs) file that:

   1. opens your temp docx file
   2. finds your title content control by title (i.e., name)
   3. deletes the control but leaves its contents
   4. saves and closes the temp docx
3. Runs the VBScript
4. Reads the temp docx file back in as an rdox object
5. Cleans up the temp files
6. Returns your rdox object

```
delete_title_content_control <- function(x) {
  
  if(Sys.info()['sysname'] != "Windows"){
    stop('The this function requires Windows operating system.')
  }

  tryCatch(
    { print(x, target = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep=""))) },
    error = function(cond) { stop("x is not a Word document.") }
  )

  print(x, target = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")))

  writeLines(
    c(
      'Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")',
      'objWord.Visible = False',
      'objWord.DisplayAlerts = False',
      paste('Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("', normalizePath(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")), '")', sep=""),
      'For Each objCC In doc.ContentControls',
      '    If objCC.Title = "Title" Then objCC.Delete',
      'Next',
      'doc.Saved = False',
      'doc.Save',
      'doc.Close (TRUE)',
      'objWord.Quit'
    ),
    con = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep="")),
    sep = "\n",
    useBytes = FALSE
  )

  shell(shQuote(normalizePath(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep="")))), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")

  x <- officer::read_docx(path = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")))

  invisible(file.remove(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep=""))))

  invisible(file.remove(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep=""))))

  invisible(x)
}
```

### Then Do About As Before

```
library(officer)

# example file from google link
sample_doc1 <- read_docx("sample_doc1.docx")

# add a linebreak to match your question example
sample_doc1 <- body_add_break(sample_doc1)

# manage cursor position so body_add_docx() works as expected
sample_doc1 <- cursor_begin(sample_doc1)

# convert title content control to text
sample_doc1_title_as_text <- delete_title_content_control(sample_doc1)

#  write out to use in body_add_docx()
print(sample_doc1_title_as_text, "sample_doc1_title_as_text.docx")

# example file from google link
# - edited by hand to set document title property to tomorrow
# - and change text to world
sample_doc2 <- read_docx("sample_doc2.docx")

# manage cursor position so body_add_docx() works as expected
sample_doc2 <- cursor_begin(sample_doc2)

# stack as in question example
as_desired <- body_add_docx(
  sample_doc2, # note, resulting doc is retaining this title property
  src = "sample_doc1_title_as_text.docx",
  pos = "before"
)

# save desired document
print(as_desired, "as_desired.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great, I could not have done in a million years! You are the vbs script in R master and well worth the bounty. I hope that others might benefit from these functions, or modifying these functions to their specs. I googled around a lot and couldn't find much beyond the basics on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (for Windows) using inspiration from the [officerWinTools](https://github.com/joshmire/officerWinTools/) package.

### First Define a Custom Function

This function:

1. Writes your rdox object to a temp docx file
2. Writes a temp VBScript (.vbs) file that:

   1. opens your temp docx file
   2. finds your title field by code contents (since it does not have a name and may be in an unknown position in the document)
   3. converts the field to text
   4. saves and closes the temp docx
3. Runs the VBScript
4. Reads the temp docx file back in as an rdox object
5. Cleans up the temp files
6. Returns your rdox object

```
unlink_title_field <- function(x) {
  
  if(Sys.info()['sysname'] != "Windows"){
    stop('The this function requires Windows operating system.')
  }

  tryCatch(
    { print(x, target = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep=""))) },
    error = function(cond) { stop("x is not a Word document.") }
  )

  print(x, target = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")))

  writeLines(
    c(
      'Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")',
      'objWord.Visible = False',
      'objWord.DisplayAlerts = False',
      paste('Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("', normalizePath(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")), '")', sep=""),
      'For Each fieldLoop In doc.Fields',
      '    If fieldLoop.Code.Text = "DOCPROPERTY " & Chr(34) & "title" & Chr(34) Then fieldLoop.Unlink',
      'Next',
      'doc.Saved = False',
      'doc.Save',
      'doc.Close (TRUE)',
      'objWord.Quit'
    ),
    con = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep="")),
    sep = "\n",
    useBytes = FALSE
  )

  shell(shQuote(normalizePath(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep="")))), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")

  x <- officer::read_docx(path = file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep="")))

  invisible(file.remove(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.docx", sep=""))))

  invisible(file.remove(file.path(paste(getwd(), "/temp.vbs", sep=""))))

  invisible(x)
}
```

### Then Do As Before

But this time use the custom function and append the unlinked version of doc1:

```
library(officer)

# Set dates for docx1 and docx2
date1 <- format(Sys.Date(), "%A, %B %d, %Y")
date2 <- format(Sys.Date() +1, "%A, %B %d, %Y")

# Create docx1 with date1 as field
docx1 <- read_docx()
docx1 <- set_doc_properties(docx1, title = date1)
fp1 <- fpar(
  ftext("Hello"), 
  run_linebreak(),
  run_word_field(field = "DOCPROPERTY \"title\""),
  run_pagebreak()
)
docx1 <- body_add_fpar(docx1, value = fp1)
print(docx1, "doc1.docx")

# Create docx1_unlinked with date1 as text
docx1_unlinked <- unlink_title_field(docx1)
print(docx1_unlinked, "doc1_unlinked.docx")

# Create docx2 with date2 as field, and add docx1_unlinked as 
# "as_desired.docx" to show how date1 does not update to date2
docx2 <- read_docx()
docx2 <- set_doc_properties(docx2, title = date2)
fp2 <- fpar(
  ftext("World"),
  run_linebreak(),
  run_word_field(field = "DOCPROPERTY \"title\"")
)
docx2 <- body_add_fpar(docx2, value = fp2)
docx2 <- body_add_docx(docx2, "doc1_unlinked.docx", pos = "before")
print(docx2, "as_desired.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your response answers the question I asked and I have credited accordingly. Unfortunately for me, I learned that Microsoft has two types of the fields: Legacy Fields and ActiveX Content Controls. The officer package's set_doc_properties must operate on the Legacy type, but mine are ActiveX Content Control, which the macros don't work on! This is the reason I struggled so much. Here is more on it in case anyone else goes down this road. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-you-convert-activex-content-controls-to/0c7b00db-ab05-4d6d-9a54-5b476215a27f

Comment: Could you post an example docx file somewhere for me to take a look?

Comment: This one has the ActiveX Content Control tied to the property. You can see when you click on the field, it shows an ellipsis with the property name (Title) which you don't see with a Legacy field. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Mt5Bookp6pyb-Mw1kxfiuaEbXMrsG6KI/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=103165908016833094475&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: OK, see what you think of my other answer.